# How to get values from SOAP type?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

There are WSDL document with following:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="CurrencyTypeEnum">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
       <xsd:enumeration value="1" description="Rubles"/>
       <xsd:enumeration value="2" description="Dollars"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

When `print_r($client->__getTypes())` I get this return: (it’s okay)

```
Array
(
    [0] => int CurrencyTypeEnum
}
```

**Question:** How I can get word «Rubles» from SOAP answer using SOAP extension from PHP?

*Already tried to find it myself, but without some results.* Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not listed, you can only get them from the XML.

For example, the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project extract them from the schema in  order to generate a constants class such as https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator/blob/382ebfa6e636339bdfbd1eefd10f1d24a584cca3/tests/resources/generated/ValidApiPhonebookSortOptionApi.php

Comment: Have you some example how to get it from SimpleXML?

Comment: Loading the WSDL with DOMDocument and using the methods provided by DOM is simple so where's the issue? What's your point? What's your needs? There is no way to get the values from the SOAP extension, that's it!

Comment: thanks! «DOMDocument» is keyword what I am searching